# Binding click event to child element inside directive of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I have following directive.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('ap.App')
        .directive('clearCancelFinishButtonsHtml', function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    clearFunction: '='
                },
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: 'directives/clearCancelFinishButtons.html',
                link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                    var clear= angular.element(el.find('button.clear'));
                    console.log(el.find('.clear'));
                    clear.bind("click", function () {
                        alert("here");
                    });
                }
            }
        });
})();
```

and it is pointing to the html file as follows

```
<div class="row pull-right">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" class="custom-default clear">CLEAR</button>
        <button type="button" class="custom-danger">CANCEL</button>
        <button type="button" class="custom-info" ng-click="ap.save()">FINISH</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do is grab the button with `clear` class  inside the directive and pass a click event to it. For some reason, click event to element itself seems to work but I couldn't get the hold of child element to bind it. Any help will be much appreciated.

PS.
I am using the directive as 
`<clear-cancel-finish-buttons-html id="{{$id}}" clear-function="'resetConfigurationPageInputs'">
</clear-cancel-finish-buttons-html>`

UPDATE----------

I wanted this to happen as I want to be able to dynamically add and remove function from the directive declaration itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for trying,

I got it working with the following code.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('ap.App')
        .directive('clearCancelFinishButtonsHtml', function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    clearFunction: '='
                },
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: 'directives/clearCancelFinishButtons.html',
                link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                    var buttons=el.find('button');
                    angular.forEach(buttons, function(button){
                        var buttonEl=angular.element(button);
                        if(buttonEl.hasClass("clear")){
                            buttonEl.bind("click", function () {
                              alert("here");
                          });
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        });
})();
```

Happy coding ;)

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated, `on()` should be used instead. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using ng-click?

if you do this

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
  scope.clearClick = function () { alert('click') };
}
```

and

```
<button type="button" class="custom-default clear" ng-click="clearClick()">CLEAR</button>
```

then it calls the function

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add and remove function from the directive declaration itself.

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery? because if not then the `.find()` method will only work with tag names (so class selectors won't work). So the problem here is that `el.find('.clear')` isn't getting your child element. Instead, use `document.querySelector` like this:

```
var clear= angular.element(el[0].querySelector('button.clear'));
```

If you're not including jquery in your project then you only have access to jqlite. You can see what can and can't be done with it in the [jqlite docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: Well, that selects the 'button.clear' of whole page, I just want to select the child of the specific directive.

Comment: Apararently couldn't bind function to element selected that way. Thanks for the help, man!

Comment: Ahh ok that's my bad, didn't realize you were using the `bind()` method, it has to be done with the `on()` method instead.