# How to bind events inside directive on every element children using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I want to bind a click event on every children from inside parent directive. I tried iterating through the element with angular.each but with no success

**HTML**

```
<parent-component>
      <div>First element</div>    
      <div>Second element</div>
</parent-component>
```

**SCRIPTS**

```
angular.module('demoApp')
.directive('parentComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {    
            angular.forEach(element[0].children, function (currentElement) {
                currentElement.bind('click', function () {
                    console.log('You clicked ', currentElement);
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37080825/2090579

Comment: Tried that solution, it is still not binding the click event. Also, no longer receiving " .bind() is not a function".

Comment: Solved this using the information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965627/angular-ng-click-event-delegation